# Use gremlin npm package to translate 'by' clause containing 'out'

Tags: javascript, typescript, gremlin

I am having trouble getting the npm gremlin package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gremlin) to correctly translate the bytecode for a query involving a by and out clause.

My code (typescript) is:

```
import {process, structure} from "gremlin";
const __ = process.statics;


const g = new structure.Graph().traversal();

const bytecode = g.V("aVertexId")
.project("someProp")
.by(
__.out("hasEdgeWith")
.hasLabel("People")
.values("identifier" , "name")
)
.getBytecode();

console.log(new process.Translator("g").translate(bytecode);

// Outputs:
// g.V('aVertexId').project('someProp').by([["out", "hasEdgeWith"], ["hasLabel", "People"], ["values", "identifier", "name"]])
```

I want the output to be (note the diff in the out clause in the by):

```
// g.V('aVertexId').project('someProp').by(out('hasEdgeWith').hasLabel('People').values('identifier', 'name'))
```

How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You've uncovered a really bad bug. I've created an issue here on [TINKERPOP-2403](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2403). The [fix](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/pull/1313) was fairly straightforward and will be part of 3.4.9 when it releases.

Comment: That's great to know. Thanks for following up with a fix. I'll keep an eye on this and test it out when 3.4.9 lands!